# Having Issue on Setting ArcGIS Web Adapter On Multi-tiered Deployment

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am trying to install ArcGIS Enterprise 10.5.1 on two separate physical machines called `GISSV01` and `GISSV02`. This means that there is a separate machine for each of the following:

- ArcGIS Server (**GISSV01**)
- Portal for ArcGIS (**GISSV02**)

The portal will be in charge of authentication process. Now my questions are:

- 1 - Where should I Install the `Web Adaptor` on `GISSV01` or `GISSV02` only or both?
- 2 - I need to install Portal only Portal for ArcGIS on `GISSV02`. From the point of Enterpise level, do I have to have the `ArcGIS for Server to be installed at that machine?

[image]

Comment: Please ask only one question per Question.

Comment: Don't forget that Portal wants a hosted Server instance, so usually there are TWO instance of Server, which would mean you don't have a choice about installing Portal on a non-Server host. And Server and Portal both need Web Adaptors.